# JavaScript : How to set the path to an image from a setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setattribute

I'm trying to set a path to an image in my local storage from a `setAttribute`, but despite of having set clearly its path keeps giving me this error of not found image, here part of my code:

```
if (shipLocation[0][0] == shipLocation[1][0] && i == 0) {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "../assets/patrolBoatHorizontalView.png"); // THIS IS THE PATH

}
```

***Error***

> GET http://localhost:8081/assets/patrolBoatHorizontalView.png 404 (Not
>   Found)

I'm not clear if this is the way i should put it......i'm using VisualStudio Editor and all my images are stored in assets, and the request is done from one of my components in this VueJS App

Any advice?

Comment: Where is the image located, relative to the root folder of the application (not relative to your CSS or HTML)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `require` method to load the image during the build process. `Webpack` will load the image during the build process.

**Example:**

```
if (shipLocation[0][0] == shipLocation[1][0] && i == 0) {
  var x = document.createElement("img");
  let image = require("../assets/patrolBoatHorizontalView.png");
  x.setAttribute("src", image); 
}
```

Comment: Explaining what your changes to the code does, the assumptions made, etc., in the answer itself, helps others understand the answer later.